# Eclipse GEF Adding BPMN Shapes into Editor

Tags: eclipse-gef

I have BPMN2 Models from that I am able to generate editor using GEF. But I am unable to add Pool,Lane,Start Event...

Answer (score 0):

Check whether Adapter class has been implemented in corresponding shapes edit part and notify changed has been called